# Problem integrating next-auth google provider with firestore security rules

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, next-auth, next.js14

I am building a web application with nextjs 14 in the client, nodejs/express in server, and firestore database. My application is working fine but i had no experience with firestore and now i have a complaint from firebase saying that i need to update my security rules, that i notice too late in my development and realize that i should use the firebase Oauth from the beginning but i didn't I also wanted to make use of a hibrid aproach using some of next's new features (app router)  for my auth but still managing my apis in my node server so this was my approach

[...nextauth]/route.ts

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth/next';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
import { db } from '../../../../../firebase';
import { doc, setDoc, getDoc, serverTimestamp } from 'firebase/firestore';

const GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!;
const GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!;

const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
  },
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile }) {
      if (!profile?.email) {
        throw new Error('No profile');
      }
      const userData = {
        name: profile.name || user.name,
        email: profile.email,
        bio: '',
        wishlist: [],
        eventsParticipated: [],
        isActive: true,
        hasCompletedProfile: false,
        invitationStatus: 'pending',
        privacySettings: {
          showEmail: false,
          showWishlist: true,
        },
        createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
        updatedAt: serverTimestamp(),
      };

      const userRef = doc(db, 'users', profile.email);

      try {
        const userSnap = await getDoc(userRef);

        if (!userSnap.exists()) {
          await setDoc(userRef, userData);
        } else {
          await setDoc(userRef, userData, { merge: true });
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error updating user in Firestore', error);
        throw new Error('Error updating user data');
      }

      return true;
    },
  },
};

export const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

i made a custom user model and create the firebase collection users in my db once a user login with google

Then the problem came when i tried to implement security rules to my db
the db doesn't know about my next-auth google provider.

I tried to use the firestore adapter

```
//same code above plus @firebase-adapter and cert form firebase/app imports 

const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
  },
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  adapter: FirestoreAdapter({
    credential: cert({
      projectId: serviceAccount.project_id,
      clientEmail: serviceAccount.client_email,
      privateKey: serviceAccount.private_key!.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
    }),
  }),
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile }) {
      if (!profile?.email) {
        throw new Error('No profile');
      }
//same code below
```

In my node server i was already using firestore-admin from the begining so i decide to share the same service-account.json like this

`import serviceAccount from '../../../../../../server/service-account.json';`

and when i tested i had the following error from google [image]

i tried also to eliminate the conflict removing the callback option but the error persist, it only works again if i remove the adapter, and now i only have 5 days left to update my security rules. can someone enlight me ? i have been researching about this issue 3 days now. (this is a personal project)

I was expecting that my database update with the session collection and the account collection and from there be able to update my security rules.

Comment: Can you have a look at [this thread](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B7157)? Also share your current firestore rules. Can you also share the error logs.

Comment: I was creating a conflict. My user existed already in the database, and the user schema was different from the one created by the adapter, once I erased my user the conflict ended, and Now it is working. Thanks for your answer @RoopaM, the thread you shared with me was a broken link, but because of you, I am learning to use the logs in Google Cloud.

Comment: The link was working when I shared, I guess it was deleted in between. *`but because of you, I am learning to use the logs in Google Cloud`* You mean with help of logs you have managed to solve your issue? If yes, can you share your solution as answer for better community visibility?